# Errores al instalar SQL Server 2012 (sqlwriter.msi) que luego me dice que el usuario no existe

Tags: sql, sql-server

Durante la instalación, no hay error alguno en los chequeos de requerimiento del wizard y todo está en orden. He seguido las instrucciones del video mas popular de instalación del programa en YouTube.

Al momento de instalar es donde ocurren errores, como que de pronto no detecta la ubicación de cierto archivo:

[image: como que de pronto no detecta la ubicacion de cierto archivo]

Y si no sucede eso, sucede que no detecta el usuario que especifiqué al añadir uno (simplemente hice clic en añadir usuario actual todas las veces).

Estoy sin ideas, usé *Your Unninstaller* para eliminar SQL y los registros del programa antes de intentar re-instalarlo pero si trato de instalar esto por 6ta vez, no hay razón para creer que funcione, no he hecho nada diferente.

Una vez que termino la instalación, simplemente no me deja loguearme al abrir el *SQL 2012 Management Studio*, que es el programa que quiero usar. Me dice que el usuario no existe (sólo una vez) o algún mensaje de error que no recuerdo.

¿He hecho algo mal?
¿Alguien tiene una sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Trata con otro instalador, puede ser que el que estés utilizando esté dañado. Intenta también ejecutarlo como administrador.